# How to solve the issue of two cover images being created when converting from epub2 to epub3 using pandoc?

Tags: epub, calibre, pandoc

Essentially, what happens is that when I convert from epub 2 epub 3 using pandoc by using the following line:

```
pandoc input_file.epub -t epub3 -o documents/input_file.epub
```

I get the version changed into 3 all fine, but the cover image gets doubled every single time.

Is there any work around?

What could be the issue and how do I fix it?

Is there any way to automatically convert epubs from v2 to v3 using Python or a bash script? Thanks in advance.

P.S I view books using Calibre typically.

Comment: The issue can be fixed after-the-fact, in *Calibre*. Select *Edit Book*, and a decent EPUB editor is used. Admittedly *not* a great answer, because each text would have to be edited manually.